# How to compute the following series?

Tags: sequences-and-series, power-series

Let $n\ge 0$ be an integer, I want to compute
$$
\sum_{m=0}^{\infty} \frac{1}{m!(m+n)!} x^{2m+n}.
$$
I have no idea. I tried to start with $n=0$ case, but I still don't know how to do it.

Thank you very much!

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bessel_function